# How to change Recently Viewed products price position in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, recently-viewed

How to position change **`inc.vat and ex.vat`** in Recently Viewed Products. Please check below screen-short

I want to ex.vat move first and inc.vat move second.

[image]

Please Help me.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Did you find where is it coming from? I mean is it from your theme OR custom module OR Magento default file. If you find that and see what code it contains you will solve it I think.

Comment: No, not created any custom module